# Activity is not returning to previous activity while clicking on ActionBar back navigation button

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbaractivity

My Activity is extending ActionBarActivity and we are setting a back navigation button in onCreate() :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);          
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if(getSupportActionBar()!=null)
    {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

and for back press, finishing this activity is on given overridden method but it's not moving to previous activity

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.home:
            finish();
            return true;
     }
     return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your id is wrong. so please change your id 'R.id.home' to 'android.R.id.home:'.

```
switch (item.getItemId())
{
    case android.R.id.home:
        finish();
        return true;
 }
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

please refer below code

```
@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_next);

 getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
 getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


 }

 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
 switch (item.getItemId()) {
 case android.R.id.home:

 // app icon in action bar clicked; goto parent activity.
 this.finish();
 return true;
 default:
 return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to call onBackPressed function

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            finish();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to override onBackPressed method to handle back button(home button) on ActionBar.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   super.onBackPressed();
   // your code here
   // finish();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> You have to set toolbar before get .

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);          
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar mToolBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);

    setSupportActionBar(mToolBar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Some titile);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

       mToolBar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            /**
             change code here*/
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For providing proper up navigation, you would have to:

Define the parent activity in the manifest.

```
<activity
   android:name=".MainActivity"
   android:parentActivityName=".HomeActivity"
   ....>

  <meta-data
    android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
    android:value=".HomeActivity" />
</activity>
```

And in MainActivity:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

There should be a toolbar in the xml of MainActivity. And then override the onOptionsItemSelected.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
switch (item.getItemId())
{
    case android.R.id.home:
         finish();
         return true;
 }
}
```

Instead of using finish(), you should consider using `NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this)` or other such methods of NavUtils class.

Use launchModes like singleTop to prevent reloading the parent activity.

More info on proper up navigation can be found [here](https://skillsmatter.com/skillscasts/4594-this-way-up-implementing-effective-app-navigation#showModal?modal-signup-complete).